# request.auth.uid not sent if transaction?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Using Google Cloud FireStore Im getting `PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions` for a transaction of mine. If i do the exact same operations outside the transaction it works fine.

This is a simple example of a failing transaction:

```
await db.runTransaction(async transaction => {
    const post = await transaction.get(pendingPostDocRef);
    return transaction.delete(pendingPostDocRef);
});
```

If i do the same operations outside of a transaction it works, like this:

```
const post = await pendingPostDocRef.get();
await pendingPostDocRef.delete();
```

And here is the security rules for that transaction:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
      [...]
      match /pending/{post} {
        allow read: if request.auth.uid != null;
        allow write: if request.auth.uid == '<a-specific-user-id>';
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Can anyone explain why there would be a difference? It seems like the transaction is not sending `request.auth.uid` or something?